# Make image clickable for radio button

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I am trying to replace the traditional radio button with some image. So when someone clicks on the option, the image should appear on the checkbox. My problem is, the option is not getting selected when I click on the check box. But since I have given an `for` attribute for the label, option is getting selected when I click on the label.

**updated**

here is my partially working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwaran/UB72d/)

Comment: It is working just fine in chrome 34.

Comment: Were you able to click on the square box also? for me option is getting selected only if I click on the label.

Comment: Works fine here too. However please post your code in your question.

Comment: It changes when I click on both the box and the label beside it.

Comment: SOrry.. I forgot to update the fiddle.. I have updated it now and the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwaran/UB72d/14/)

```
<ul class="pt-answers" style=" margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left:20px;">
        <li style="list-style: none;">
             <label for="q_2_1">
        <input type="radio" id="q_2_1" name="q_2" value="1">
            <img />
        Answer number one </label>

    </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
                <label for="q_2_2">
        <input type="radio" id="q_2_2" name="q_2" value="2">
            <img />
     Answer number two</label>

    </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <label for="q_2_3">
        <input type="radio" id="q_2_3" name="q_2" value="3">
        <img />
        Answer number three</label>

    </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <label for="q_2_4">
        <input type="radio" id="q_2_4" name="q_2" value="4">
              <img for="q_2_4"/>Answer number four
        </label>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/33qaD/)

```
<input type="checkbox">

<br><br>

<span style="position:relative">
  <input type="radio" >
<span>
```

**CSS**

```
/* checkbox */

input[type='checkbox'] {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: -25px;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
input[type='checkbox']:before { 
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #333434;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
input[type='checkbox']:after { 
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 17px;
  height: 6px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {           opacity: 1;
}

/*radio button*/
input[type='radio'] {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: -25px;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  margin-left: 0;
}


input[type='radio']:before { 
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #333434;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
input[type='radio']:after { 
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  -webkit-transform: none;
  top: -2px;
  left: 7px;
}
input[type='radio']:checked:after {               opacity: 1;
}
```